# EXTJs Scrollbar position with IE

Tags: extjs, scrollbar

I am using TabPanel in my application. Now I have grids and tree panel on every tab.

So whenever I scroll grid or Tree Panel and shift to second tab and then return back to first Tab, Scroll goes to the Top. That's means it doesn't preserve its position.

Also this behavior is only on IE11. In case of Chrome, it works fine. What can be possibly wrong? Can anyone help?